# Default FontFamily for PlotLabel

Tags: plotting, options, fonts

This is probably a rather basic question and I presume I am simply unable to make proper use of the `Options[]` function: I am trying to figure out what the default font (or `FontFamily`, I guess) is for `PlotLabel`.

I tried e.g. `Options[PlotLabel, FontFamily]` and some variations, but to no avail.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try

```
CurrentValue[PlotLabel, FontFamily]
```

a problem

```
GraphicsRow@Table[Plot[Sinc[x],{x,0,10},PlotLabel->f],{f,{"Label---Default",Style["Label---Times",FontFamily->"Times"],Style["Label---Courier",FontFamily->"Courier"]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @HyperGroups , I edited your post for better formatting, please feel free to modify it further.

Comment: @Silvia welcome, I'm poor in editing here,haha. Just familiar with 4-spaces and `inline` .

Comment: Markdown is a good thing, you will like it when you get more familiar. :)

Comment: This returns a value, but on my system it does not appear to be the *correct* value.  That is, this returns `"Courier"` while the label in `Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> "This is a label"]` is clearly not in Courier.  Any comment?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't know. I've added a image, plot 1 is different from plot 3, maybe some other settings in options, or StandardForm, OutputForm TraditionalForm ...so many Forms. Need some more expriments.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I believe in v.11.2.0 the default is Arial (at least on Mac OS v.10.13.6)